# Configure an app for deployment for as many device as possible

Tags: iphone, ios

I wanna to deploy a simple Iphone/Ipad application. Wanna to configure the application in Xcode so that I can deploy it and it will work on as many devices (IOS operating systems) possible. How should I configure the app to achieve this?

Comment: You might wanna submit it to App Store, then it can be installed as many devices exist.

Answer (score 3):

Make the app universal and set the **Deployment Target** to **3.0** as in the following screenshot.

[image]

To add support for the **armv6** architecture, go to the **Build Settings** tab and modify the value of **Architectures** into **$(VALID_ARCHS)** as in the following screenshot.

[image]

Then remove **armv7** from **Required Device Capabilities** in the **Info** tab as in the following screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use only features available in iOS 3.13 and lower.